# How to pause autoplay in a fancybox when user hovers the image?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have several images in iframes that all open a fancybox in the parent window. The fancybox.js is set to autoplay:true, but I would like this image-gallery to pause autoplay when a user hovers the image inside the fancybox. As soon as the users hovers away, the autoplay should resume.

Comment: could you please share your existing code related to fancybox along with your HTML code.

Comment: That's a lot of code, maybe you can check my test-page: http://fancybox-test.stainlessmedia.com where a basic page with iframes is randomly filled with thumbnail-pages, that all open up a series of images in the parent frame. I can send a zip if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Your-div").fancybox({
autoPlay:true, //Sets AutoPlay to 3 seconds********************
stopOnHover : true,
});
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Danish, thanks for your reply. I'm looking for something to pause the autoplay, not to 'quit' the fancybox all together, so something like 'autoPlayPauseOnHover' but I guess that won't work... And to have the autoplay move on when you hover out of the image.